# Can't get WPF ItemsControl to strech vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I recently started working on a small WPF project using MVVM.

I'm however runing into some trouble getting my ItemsControl to strech across the entire MainWindow. It works as expected horizontally, but vertically it does nothing.

When I change the DesignHeight in the ItemControl's view, it streches as expected so I'm tempted to believe the issue is in the MainWindow.

**The MainWindow's XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="PhoneDirectoryEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneDirectoryEditor"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PhoneDirectoryEditor.ViewModel"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:PhoneDirectoryEditor.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="660" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainWindowViewModel}" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DirectoryEntryListViewModel}">
            <vw:DirectoryEntryListView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**The ItemControl's XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneDirectoryEditor.View.DirectoryEntryListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneDirectoryEditor.View"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:PhoneDirectoryEditor.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:DirectoryEntryListViewModel}" d:DesignWidth="512" d:DesignHeight="383">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!--body content datagrid cell vertical centering-->
        <Style x:Key="BodyContentDataGridCentering" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="GhostWhite">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllDirectoryEntries}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="3,3,3,46" MaxHeight="400">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource BodyContentDataGridCentering}" Binding="{Binding Name}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Name" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource BodyContentDataGridCentering}" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Phone number" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Contact" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Delete" Tag="{Binding}" Margin="2"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Content="Search" Tag="{Binding}" Margin="150,0,0,9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="87" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Margin="3,0,0,9" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140"/>
        <Button Content="New" Tag="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,3,9" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="104" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**An image to avoid confusion**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0NHA.png

Answer (score 0):

On your `ItemsControl`, you can specify the `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

```
<ItemsControl VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ...
```

Also, make sure your `UserControl` does not have a restricted height. From what I can see right now, you are setting the max height on your `DataGrid`:

```
Margin="3,3,3,46" MaxHeight="400"
```

Comment: I put the MaxHeight in to make sure I get a scrollbard. I took it off and the buttons were moved down, out of the window sadly

http://i.imgur.com/lprYbaR.png

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the max height that you had on your datagrid `MaxHeight="400"`

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllDirectoryEntries}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="3,3,3,46" MaxHeight="400">
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Put your DataGrid and those two Buttons together with their Textbox in a DockPanel with its LastChildFill = true.

According to the property aforementioned, your DataGrid should be added as the last child of the DockPanel so add those 3 controls into a StackPanel with Orientation Horizontal and after it, place your DataGrid.

Here is an example of how this works:

```
<Window x:Class="GridHeightStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="system:String" x:Key="days">
            <system:String>Item1</system:String>
            <system:String>Item2</system:String>
            <system:String>Item3</system:String>
            <system:String>Item4</system:String>
            <system:String>Item5</system:String>
            <system:String>Item6</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <DockPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="30">
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="test text" />
        <Button  Content="Search"/>
        <Button  Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <Border BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="2">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource days}" FontSize="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

and the result:

[image]

I've colored the Border of the DataGrid so you can see it expanded and the Bottom items staying on their place.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I tried it but it still only stretches horizontally

Comment: For the downvoter: have you even tried my example? It is as simple as possible and it does its job perfectly.

Comment: @Robert get rid of the MaxHeight on the DataGrid and just add Height on the DockPanel, in my example i took Height="30".

Comment: I've just made an update to prove the obvious. Good luck!